# C# deleting dynamic textboxes by checkboxing

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textbox

I am writing a code in C# I have 2 Forms and the code creates textboxes and corresponding checkboxes dynamically. The code I wrote creates dynamic textboxes and checkboxes successfully. However, I am not able to delete the row of textboxes in a selected checkbox line.

```
public void CreateTextBox(int i, StringReader sr)
        {
        ProductForm form2 = new ProductForm();
        _cb = new CheckBox[i];
        form2.Visible = true;
        form2.Activate();

        int x = 10;
        int y = 30;
        int width = 100;
        int height = 20;


        for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
        {

            String line = sr.ReadLine();
            String[] line_ = line.Split(new char[] {'\t'});

            String cbName = "chkBox_" + n.ToString();



            _cb[n] = new CheckBox();
            _cb[n].Name = cbName;
            _cb[n].Location = new Point(2, y);
            _cb[n].Checked = false;
            form2.Controls.Add(_cb[n]);
            if (line.Length > 3)
            {

                for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
                {
                    String name = "txtBox_" + row.ToString();
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.Name = name;
                    tb.Text = line_[row].ToString();
                    tb.Location = new Point(x, y);
                    tb.Height = height;
                    if (row == 1)
                    {
                        tb.Width = width * row;
                    }

                    if (row == 3)
                    {
                        tb.Width = width * 5;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tb.Width = width - 20;
                    }
                    x += 10 + width;
                    form2.Controls.Add(tb);

                }
            }
            x = 10;
            y += 25;

        }

    }

    private void DeleteTextBoxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here should I add a code in order to delete dynamically created 
        //textboxes by clicking checkbox and button

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like winforms, but can you please tag whether this is about winforms/webforms/WPF please?

Comment: Its pretty obvious that he wants someone to fill in the blank on his function.

Comment: yes I need a code for  DeleteTextBoxButton_Click button which will let me delete a whole line of textboxes for clicked checkboxes.

Comment: A screenshot would be very helpful.  Does clicking the checkbox next to the textbox cause the textbox to get deleted or is it that you need to delete all textboxes with their corresponding checkbox checked?

Comment: Each line has  4 textboxes and 1 checkbox. 
When I click a checkbox and than click the button, code will delete the entire line of textboxes. I can select textboxes with their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your question. But if I am right, this could do the trick.

SOLUTION1: While creating all the controls, add them to a `List<Controls>`. When you are checking the checkbox to delete the row, get the name of the checkbox, search it in the `List<Controls>`. So this way can get the index of the row of the checkbox clicked. Now delete the controls of that rows.

SOLUTION2: Create your controls in a TablelayoutPanel and everything will be easy.

**EDIT**

Copy paste everything in the form1, se btn_click as a event handler for a button. Let the size of the form a bit big. Everything should work fine now. If not working, let me know.

```
class MyControl
{
    public TextBox txt1 { get; set; }
    public TextBox txt2 { get; set; }
    public TextBox txt3 { get; set; }
    public TextBox txt4 { get; set; }
    public CheckBox cb { get; set; }

    public MyControl(TextBox txt1, TextBox txt2, TextBox txt3, TextBox txt4, CheckBox cb)
    {
        this.txt1 = txt1;
        this.txt2 = txt2;
        this.txt3 = txt3;
        this.txt4 = txt4;
        this.cb = cb;
    }

}


    List<MyControl> list = new List<MyControl>();
    public int x = 50, n = 1;
    TextBox txtTemp, txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4;
    CheckBox cbTemp;
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtTemp = new TextBox();
        txtTemp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, x);
        txtTemp.Name = "txt1_" + n;
        txt1 = txtTemp;

        txtTemp = new TextBox();
        txtTemp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, x);
        txtTemp.Name = "txt2_" + n;
        txt2 = txtTemp;

        txtTemp = new TextBox();
        txtTemp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, x);
        txtTemp.Name = "txt3_" + n;
        txt3 = txtTemp;

        txtTemp = new TextBox();
        txtTemp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(350, x);
        txtTemp.Name = "txt4_" + n;
        txt4 = txtTemp;

        cbTemp = new CheckBox();
        cbTemp.Name = "cb1_" + n;
        cbTemp.Enter += new EventHandler(cbTemp_Enter);
        cbTemp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(490, x);

        this.Controls.Add(txt1);
        this.Controls.Add(txt2);
        this.Controls.Add(txt3);
        this.Controls.Add(txt4);
        this.Controls.Add(cbTemp);

        list.Add(new MyControl(txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, cbTemp));

        x += 40;
        n++;
    }

    void cbTemp_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)) == DialogResult.No)
            return;

        CheckBox cbMain = (CheckBox)sender;
        int index = Search(cbMain);

        this.Controls.Remove(list[index].txt1);
        this.Controls.Remove(list[index].txt2);
        this.Controls.Remove(list[index].txt3);
        this.Controls.Remove(list[index].txt4);
        this.Controls.Remove(list[index].cb);
    }

    private int Search(CheckBox cbMain)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        foreach (MyControl item in list)
        {
            if(cbMain.Name == item.cb.Name)
                temp = list.IndexOf(item);
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: I am trying the first solution now. The solution 2 sounds good but I have no experience in that.

Comment: for List, create a class (MyControls) with public control properties (like Textbox, Buttons and whatever you have). On creating each row add a MyControl object to List. You are done with nearly everything.

Comment: rapsalands can you write an example of how I can create a List and MyControl object?

Answer (score 1):

For WinForms, I recommend putting the generated TextBoxes into the Tag field of the CheckBox.  Then keep a managed list of all CheckBoxes.  Once they click the delete button, iterate through the collection of CheckBoxes.  If their state is checked, pull the TextBox out of the Tag field, remove it from the form collection, then delete it.

**NOTE:** This code is untested but should work in principle.

**UPDATE:** Reading your latest comment, instead of storing a single TextBox in the Tag, just create another List of them and store the entire list in the tag.  Then iterate through those in the delete method.

```
private List<CheckBox> _checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>();

public void CreateTextBox( int i, StringReader r )
{
   // ... do your stuff here
   _cb[n].Tag = tb;
   // ... finish up
   _checkboxes.Add( _cb[n] );
}

public void DeleteTextBoxButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   foreach( var cb in _checkboxes )
   {
       if( cb.Checked )
       {
           TextBox tb = cb.Tag as TextBox;
           if( tb != null )
           {
              form2.Controls.Remove( tb );
           }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I will do exactly like that either tag or via name field. However, I do not know how can I access my checkboxes and textboxes in my button function? How can I iterate it in a foreach or for loop.

Comment: The _checkboxes property in my sample is defined at class-level outside of the methods so it will be visible inside the DeleteTextBoxButton_Click method.

Comment: I really got lost in your solution. I tried but could not make it work for me. Still trying on it.