# How do I remove a specific panel through event handling in my FlowlayoutPanel for my Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

For my C# Windows Form Application, I have created a flowlayoutpanel that contains several panels. Inside the panel, I have a button "Clear" for each and every single panel.

How do I write the event handler for the code for the button "Clear" such that once I have click the button, the panel would sort of be "Removed" from the flowlayoutpanel.

This is a short part of the code of the adding of panels to the flowlayoutpanel.

```
        nFlowPanel.Controls.Add(createNotificationPanel());
        nFlowPanel.Controls.Add(createNotificationPanel());
        nFlowPanel.Controls.Add(createNotificationPanel());
        nFlowPanel.Controls.Add(createNotificationPanelImpt());
        nFlowPanel.Controls.Add(createNotificationPanelImpt());
```

and this is the code for the button "Clear"

```
Button btnClear = new Button
        {
            Text = "Clear",
            Name = "btnClear",
            Location = new Point(416, 17)
        };
        p.Controls.Add(btnClear);
        btnClear.Click += new EventHandler(buttonClear_Click);
```

So what should i write in the following method to have the effect of removing e.g. the second panel that was added in the first part of code I have written?

```
void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

**EDIT**

the code for creating my panel is

```
var p = new Panel 
        {
             BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle , 
             Size = new Size(506,100),
             Name = "notifyPanel"
        };
```

and the code for creating my FlowLayoutPanel is

```
var nFlowPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel
        {
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown,
            WrapContents = false,
            AutoScroll = true,
            Size = new Size(530, 377),
            Location = new Point(13, 145)
        };
```

and the code for my button clear is

```
void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Control)sender;
        var panel = button.Parent.Controls["notifyPanel"];
        panel.Dispose();
    }
```

however it gives the error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
on the panel.Dispose() line.

anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Controls.Remove() method is *very* dangerous, it doesn't dispose the control.  Which will live on, moved to the so-called parking window, using up both Windows and managed resources.  After a bit less than 10,000 times doing this it crashes your program when Windows is no longer willing to let you create any more windows.

Call the control's Dispose() method instead.  That also automatically removes the control from its container.

```
void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var panel = nFlowPanel.Controls["notifyPanel"];
    panel.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: but how does the method calls the nFlowPanel? the event handler does not have that attribute in it.

Comment: The *sender* argument give you a reference to the control that generated the event.  var ctl = (Control)sender;  It's Parent property gives you a reference to the panel.

Comment: hi i'm sorry, but i am still pretty new to programming. do you mind explaining it in more simply or show me the code to do it? thank you very much.

Comment: Code added.  Be sure to set the panel's Name property to "somename" when you create it.

Comment: hi, thanks for the code. however when i use this code and i run my application, after clicking the clear button, it gives me the error on line the line panel.Dispose(); with the error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object. any idea why did that happen?

Comment: `Be sure to set the panel's Name property`

Comment: i did set it. but my GUI is drawn using code instead of the drag and drag functionality of visual studio. does it works the same way? refer to my above edited to see what i meant.

Comment: It works the same way.  I did notice that you added the button to something called "p", not nFlowPanel.  Which probably means that the button's Parent is not the flow panel.  Post updated.

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. unfortunately, there is a error again. it says The name 'nFlowPanel' does not exist in the current context. my nFlowPanel is also a GUI drawn using code.

Comment: This is like driving in the dark with broken headlights.  I'm fed up with this question, good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
nFlowPanel.Controls.Remove((sender as Button).Parent);
```

Comment: but it is in a different method, how does the method take the object from nFlowPanel?

Comment: This is a very dangerous resource leak.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use List for this. Before adding `Panels` in the `FlowLayoutpanel`, add them in the List. Then just remove the indexed panel from the flowlayoutpanel.

```
Panel pnlTemp = (panel)list[index];
nFlowPanel.Controls.Remove(pnlTemp);
```

To get the index of the button you have to add your buttons also to your list and after clicking any button, search the button in the list and get the index of the button where it is saved in the list. If my code is unclear, let me know. but I feel your task is that complex. [I am not sure but this link may be of some help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667141/c-sharp-deleting-dynamic-textboxes-by-checkboxing/7667349#7667349)

Hope it helps.